# Python regex - identifying words with preceding symbol

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to split a target sentence into composite pieces for a later function using re.split() and the regex

> (@?\w+)(\W+)

Ideally, this would split words and non-word characters in a generated list, preserving both as separate list items, with the exception of the "@" symbol which could precede a word. If there is an @ symbol before a word, I want to keep it as a cohesive item in the split. My example is below.

My test sentence is as follows:

> this is a test of proper nouns @Ryan

So the line of code is:

> re.split(r'(@?\w+)(\W+)', "this is a test of proper nouns @Ryan")

The list that I want to generate would include "@Ryan" as a single item but, instead, it looks like this

> ['', 'this', ' ', '', 'is', ' ', '', 'a', ' ', '', 'test', ' ', '', 'of', ' ', '', 'proper', ' ', '', 'nouns', ' @', 'Ryan']

Since the first container has the @ symbol, I would have thought that it would be evaluated first but that is apparently not the case. I have tried using lookaheads or removing @ from the \W+ container to no avail.

https://regex101.com/r/LeezvP/1

Comment: Why do you have a char[] inside of a string. That is just wrong format, I think - all the "","",'","'''',""

Comment: @ColeHenrich - I don't follow. The regex I'm using is (@?\w+)(\W+), there are no brackets and the only char is "@." If you mean the output, I'm preserving punctuation and that's how re.split() works with the present regex, which I am seeking advice on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following(written and tested in Python 3.8.5). considering that you need to remove empty/null items in your list. This will give output where `@` is together with words.

```
##First split the text/line here and save it to list named li.
li=re.split(r'(@?\w+)(?:\s+)', "this is a test of proper nouns @Ryan")
li
['', 'this', '', 'is', '', 'a', '', 'test', '', 'of', '', 'proper', '', 'nouns', '@Ryan']

##Use filter to remove nulls in list li.
list(filter(None, li))
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'of', 'proper', 'nouns', '@Ryan']
```

Simple explanation would be, use split function with making 1 capturing group which has an optional `@` followed by words and 1 non-capturing group which has spaces one or more occurrences in it. This will place null elements in list, so to remove them use filter function.

***NOTE:*** As per OP's comments nulls/spaces may be required, so in that case one could refer following code; which worked for OP:

```
li=re.split(r'(@?\w+)(\s+|\W+)', "this is a test of proper nouns @Ryan")
```

Comment: Preserving the nulls goes part and parcel with preserving the punctuation but by putting your regex in, and changing/capturing the second half like so: (@?\w+)((?:\s+|\W)) I was able to get it to work: https://regex101.com/r/7Eh2iz/1. Thanks.

Comment: @cswat, your welcome, happy to help. So you could change your regex to `(@?\w+)(\s+|\W+)` since you are capturing them, by that you need not to crate 1 non-capturing group inside 2nd capturing group, cheers.

Comment: That is a smart split. I think I have found an alternative with matching as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could also match using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) and use an alternation `|` matching the desired parts.

```
(?:[^@\w\s]+|@(?!\w))+|\s+|@?\w+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^@\w\s]+` Match 1+ times any char except `@` word char or whitespace char
  - `|` Or
  - `@(?!\w)` Match @ when not directly followed by a word char
- `)+` Close the group and match 1+ times
- `|` Or
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars to keep them as a separate match in the result
- `|` Or
- `@?\w+` Match `@` directly followed by 1+ word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gnne3c/1)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"(?:[^@\w\s]+|@(?!\w))+|\s+|@?\w+"

print(re.findall(pattern, "this is a test of proper nouns @Ryan"))

# Output
# ['this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'test', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'proper', ' ', 'nouns', ' ', '@Ryan']

print(re.findall(pattern, "this @Ryan #$@test@123@4343@@$%$test@1#$#$@@@1@@@@"))

# Output
# ['this', ' ', '@Ryan', ' ', '#$', '@test', '@123', '@4343', '@@$%$', 'test', '@1', '#$#$@@', '@1', '@@@@']
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex, `@?\w+|\b(?!$)` should meet your requirement.

**Explanation at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mPtvKm/1):**

[image]

```
1st Alternative @\w
    @ matches the character @ literally (case sensitive)
    ? matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    \w matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
    + matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
2nd Alternative \b(?!$)
    \b assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
    Negative Lookahead (?!$)
        Assert that the Regex below does not match
        $ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but this doesn't quite do it. While it does provide a match for all words and the @ symbol, using re.split with this regex and the sample sentence produces "['', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '']" and the regex101 link confirms that we're not matching on non-word characters.

Comment: Please don't upload screenshots of text. How difficult can it be to copy that text and paste it here?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - The screenshot is only for the explanation; not for the code. The code is written in the text only.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285554/843953 reasons 1 and 2 still apply. More importantly, some people's employers block image sharing sites, and some people have low bandwidth which prevents them from viewing images. Your answer becomes significantly less helpful without the image.

Comment: The `MATCH INFORMATION` section at regex101 confirms that this should meet your requirement. Instead of splitting the string, get the group using a matcher. I do not have expertise in Python and therefore I can only demonstrate [how it works in Java](https://ideone.com/o7PCg3).